# Specifically calling a nested function outside of the outer function Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, printing, nested, call

How would I be able to run the nested def function only `function2()` from outside of the def functions. So I want to specifically run the `function2()` and skip `function1()`. How would I be able to do that the call for the inner function `function1.functions2()` does not work.

Code:

```
def function1(): # outer function
    print ("Hello from outer function")
    def function2(): # inner function
        print ("Hello from inner function")

function1.functions2() #Doesnt work
```

Expected Output:

```
Hello from inner function
```

Comment: This really depends on why you're nesting the functions. You can't do this like you're attempting to, but you could make the first function a class or something with `function2` as a method, or return `function2` from `function1`, then do `function1()()`.

Comment: You probably don't want these to be nested functions in the first place.  Usually the point of a locally defined function is to make sure nothing outside that function depends on it.

Comment: @Samwise  A use case is for  `airflow` `PythonVirtualenvOperator`'s:  they require an entry point that can not see other functions in the same file. So to share logic used by that entry point requires exposing inner functions.

Comment: Surely you would just define the shared logic in a different scope and then have the inner function call that?